# can't make the pictureboxes to show up

Tags: c#, winforms

I created that snippet in a class for the black pawns (I am making a chess game). The line with `Controls.Add(newPictureBox);` was supposed to make the picture boxes show up when I start (that code have a refrense in the form_load) but when I press start only the board shows up... that line worked for making the board but not for the line of pawns also its shows the problem 'A circular control reference has been made. A control cannot be owned by or parented to itself.' when i start

```
// event handler of creating the pawns
    public static void Create(PictureBox[] BlackpawnsPictureboxes, Button[,] board)
    {
        const int tileSize = 50;
```

`            // initialize the "black pawns line"

```
        BlackpawnsPictureboxes = new PictureBox[8];

        // handle the line of the pawns
        for (var m = 0; m < 8; m++)
        {
            var newPictureBox = new PictureBox
            {
                Size = new Size(tileSize, tileSize),
                Location = board[1, m].Location
            };

            // add to our of Pictureboxes for future use
            BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m] = newPictureBox;

            // setting the image
            BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m].Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\USER\source\repos\chess\chess\pieces\כלים שחורים\pown.jpg");

            // add to Form's Controls so that they show up
            BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m].Controls.Add(newPictureBox);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the board? Another PBox?

Comment: Should   Controls.Add(newPictureBox);
be   Controls.Add(BlackpawnsPictureboxes[m]);   ?

Comment: @TaW its a 2D button array of the board

Comment: @Stefan for some reason it wont accept the conrols that is one of the problems when i used it in a function it worked but here in a class it doesnt...

Comment: maybe i wasnt very clear ill edit and add that

Comment: sory that I wasn't clear before I guess i forgot to write it...

Comment: Maybe the pawns sit below the board? You would have to add a pawn to the control it is supposed to sit on, ie `board[1, m].Controls.Add(newpbox)`. Then make Location = (0,0) or so..! - Btw: This whole setup is not very promising; many have tried and most have failed due to the transparency limitation in Winforms. Imo drawing the board onto the Form or some container may be a simpler solution..

Comment: @TaW well that fixed the eror but they still wont show up

Comment: _that fixed the error_ What? Show the new code!

Comment: @TaW I edited to the new code for some reason it spited the code to two at a comment line but its all one code